# VBA code to analyze a HTML table based off certain conditions

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

So I need to screen scrape data off a website and return it to a spreadsheet based off if a charge amount matched as well the date was the most recent in the table. If there was simply one line in the table, the macro pulls that accordingly. So most of the code is good, I am connected to the website, pulling everything effectively. Where I am struggling is getting the logic to work where the two amounts match as well as the date being the most recent in the HTML table.

I guess what my question is how do I loop through Item(5) the column of that table and specify it to choose the most recent date, also setting the value so that it only finds the one equal to the charge amount. I only want a one to one match. I am new to this so if anyone wants to help me I would greatly appreciate it.

```
Set IHEC = iHTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("TR")
If IHEC.Length > 2 Then
For index = 0 to IHEC.Length - 1
Set IHEC_TD = IHEC.Item(index).getElementsByTagName("TD")
Do Until IHEC.Length <2 Or index = IHEC.Length - 1
If IHEC.TD.Item(3).innerText = myBilledAmount Then
myItem1 = IHEC_TDItem(0).innerText
myItem2 = IHEC_TDItem(1).innerText
myItem3 = IHEC_TDItem(2).innerText
myItem4 = IHEC_TDItem(3).innerText
myItem5 = IHEC_TDItem(4).innerText
myItem6 = IHEC_TDItem(5).innerText
myItem7 = IHEC_TDItem(6).innerText
myItem8 = IHEC_TDItem(7).innerText
myItem9 = IHEC_TDItem(8).innerText
End If
End If
Loop
Next Index
```